# UbikLoadPack : Video Streaming load testing and how to emit requests from multiple IPs

Tags: video-streaming, load-testing, http-live-streaming, spoofing, ubikloadpack

We're using [UbikLoadPack](https://ubikloadpack.com) to load test streams delivered in :

- Apple HLS
- MPEG-DASH
- MS Smooth
- Adobe HDS

We now want to distribute the load from multiple IPs to check our load balancing policies and localization rules.

How can we do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1 : You have multiple IP interfaces for 1 machine**

You can use the IP Spoofing Host/IP field and put :

- ${ip}

[image: ULP VS]

- Add a [CSV Data Set](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) element that will reference a CSV file containing the IPs you have and declare **ip** variable

[image: CSV Data Set with ip variable]

**Option 2 : You don't or want to use multiple machines, you can have a look at distributed testing**

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html

For reporting, pay particular attention to requirements:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#configuration_requirements

**Option 3 : Use the Cloud**

Run from the Cloud using any cloud provider or PAAS solutions like:

- [Redline13](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2015/11/jmeter-video-stream-tutorial-with-ubikloadpack/), UbikLoadPack is available on it
- [Blazemeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/) : UbikLoadPack is compatible using Taurus test type to run
- Flood.io